# Reduce PWM Frequency Arduino DUE

Tags: arduino-due, pwm, timers

I'm newbie in arduino due. I need to reduce the default PWM frequency of arduino Due. Anyone have any tutorial to do this? (Frequencys like 25hz, 50Hz for example)

I read in some posts, if i change the PWM frequency, i make changes in internal timers of arduino and i loss functions like delay(), millis(), etc.

Exits any form to not lose these functions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 25 and 50 hz square wave can be generated by software easily

Answer (score -1):

The [Palatis Softpwm library](https://github.com/Palatis/arduino-softpwm) can generate PWM on any digital pin with (almost) any frequency. Example for 25Hz:

```
#include <SoftPWM.h>
SOFTPWM_DEFINE_CHANNEL(0, DDRB, PORTB, PORTB2);  //Arduino pin 10
void setup() {
  // begin with 25Hz pwm frequency
  Palatis::SoftPWM.begin(25);
  Palatis::SoftPWM.set(0, value); // value is 0 to 255 just like normal Arduino analogWrite
}
```